# Show that $T_n=\min \{t>T_{n-1} :|B(t)-B(T_{n-1})|=1\}$ is a stopping time for BM and that the $T_n-T_{n-1}$ are IID.

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, stopping-times

We define $T_0=0$ and $T_n=\min \{t>T_{n-1} :|B(t)-B(T_{n-1})|=1\}$, where $B $ deonotes Brownian motion. I have the following two questions:

> (1) Show that for every $n ,\  \ T_n $ is a stopping time and  (2) the waiting times $T_n - T_{n-1 }  $  are independent and identically distributed.

---

For (1) we of course proceed by induction. We have to show that given any $0<s$, $\{T_n \le s \} \in \mathcal F_s$ where $F_s $ is a filtration for the brownian motion. Then I'm a bit lost: I can see the following. By sample continuity we could reduce the minimum over $\mathbb R $ to a minimum over a countable set. Also from sample continuity we have that for any $t $,  $\{t< T_{n-1 } \}  \in \mathcal F_{n-1 } $. And $\omega \mapsto |B(t)(\omega)-B(T_{n-1 })(\omega) |$ is   $\mathcal F_{T_{n-1 } }  $-measurable.

For (2) I know that from the strong Markov property for Brownian motion $T_n $ must be distributed as $T_{n-1 } $. Does the independence of the increments also follow from the Strong markov property? And how do we find the distribution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For (1), we can use this proposition.

> **Proposition.** Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be an adapted process with values in a metric space $(E, d)$. Assume that the sample paths of $X$ are continuous, and $F$ be a closed subset of $E$. Then
>   $$T_F=\inf\{t\geq0: X_t \in F\}$$
>   is a stopping time.

$T_1<\infty$ is a stopping time by this proposition. Then we use induction. Note that $T_n-T_{n-1}=\inf\{t\geq0: |B_{t+T_{n-1}}-B_{T_{n-1}}|=1\}$. Let $X_t=B_{t+T_{n-1}}-B_{T_{n-1}}$, then for any $\omega\in\Omega$, $X_t(\omega)$ is a continuous function in $t$. An application of this proposition implies that $T_n-T_{n-1}<\infty$ is a stopping time, so $T_n$ is a stopping time by induction. (If $S$ and $T$ are stopping tmes then $S+T$ is a stopping time.

For (2), we use the strong Markov property, which aseerts that $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ defined above is a Brownian motion independent of $\mathscr F_{T_{n-1}}$( Here we need to use that $T_{n-1}<\infty$ a.s.) Since $T_{n-1},T_{n-2}\in \mathscr F_{T_{n-1}}$, we have $T_n-T_{n-1}\perp T_{n-1}-T_{n-2}$. Since $X_t$ is a Brownian motion, we have $T_n-T_{n-1}\overset{d}{=}T_1$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Don't you need right-continuity of the filtration for this to work?

Comment: Ah, I misread. Nevermind.

Comment: Great answer! There is one question that remains though. What happens with the proposition you cites when the sample paths are only assumed to be almost surely continuous?

Comment: @MrFranzén I'm not 100% sure about my answer. There maybe a problem for those $\omega$ satisfying $T_{n-1}(\omega)=\infty$. As for your problem, I think we may need the completeness of the filtration to make the proposition valid in your setting. In that case the discontinue paths are of measure zero and belong to all $\mathscr F$. I will think for more time to see if my proof in part (1) is right.